# How can I migrate The Sims 3 Expansion Packs and Stuff Packs games from my old laptop to a new computer?

Tags: technical-issues, the-sims-3, the-sims

I am writing to you this message because I need some help regarding The Sims 3 and its EP and SP installation.

I own all of the EPs and SPs of the Sims 3 game and I actually have the original physical version of the games which come with the CDs and the boxes but all of them were installed on my old computer (laptop) which I do not use anymore because it is too old to run the games .The question is how am I able to have all of the EP and SP I originally own on my new computer. Can I do that by copy/pasting the original EA folder and what's inside or there's another way.All of my CDs are legal but I hadn't thought of signing them up with Origin back then and I have a big problem now.Please help me! The only CD I still have is the base game The Sims 3 and TS3 and Into the Future I've lost the other CDs since I didn't need them for playing the game!!! I really need some help.What should I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Your only real option is to find those disks.

Comment: Really?I guess I will have to buy them again...all of them :/

Comment: There's a lot of options here. Some of them just require a lot less work...

Comment: This post was active two days ago, but there's no additional answers here. I don't have the rep to see it, so I can only surmise that it was either spam, or suggested what I *would* and what you should do, but it is against this site's rules to promote software piracy. <cough>

Answer (score 1):

*feasible; probability of success: low. probability for error : HIGH*

---

You need to use the same user name on your new computer.

You would need to copy, and place in the same-named locations:

- the My Games \ EA folder
- the entire game

And then export/import all relevant registry entries.*

And possibly several other steps that I can't remember, because I probably just went *the easy route*. I don't think there's any other files in e.g., "AppData".

There are websites that will generate registry entries for you, provided you have the CD keys. Which you should still have on the cases.

You're also in luck, because *Into the Future* is the disk you'll need to run the game.

*I leave you little instruction here, as you should be well-versed before you even touch the registry on your new computer.

---

*Moving game to new computer without disc?*

'If you no longer have the disks, I recommend registering your games in Origin which will give you a digital download copy of the games. You need the serial numbers from the box or manual to do that; if those are also missing you can [find them](http://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/forum/?topic=685.0) on your desktop if the games are still installed.'  –[Carl's](http://www.carls-sims-4-guide.com/forum/?topic=6628.0)

Comment: Hello @Mazura, On your instruction above you have put a link which leads to Carl and Pam's The Sims Forum where I read something I would like to ask you about. Somewhere on the site link you posted above says " There's no reason to copy those; you can't install from them and they don't work without the correct entries in the registry which the installer makes".My question is, is there a way to put an Installer (maybe an InstallShield-Set Up exe. for TS3 or something) in *The My Games/EA Folder in order to reinstall the Expansion Packs and Stuff Packs as it would happen if I had the disks?

Comment: @PrincessLeiaOrgana - Allow me to reword that quote: "There's no reason to copy those files if you can't create the appropriate registry entries which the installer makes." (which you can attempt to transfer manually or use a web site to generate one) - You can't just "put" an installer. If you have the *setup.exe* then you basically have "the disk".

Comment: ohh :/, Thank you for helping me and making that clear!